Not able to use My website(https) as iframe in index.html page. I'm using nginx in server
Scenario:
I have a web application, Now client have also requested for an android application.
Now rather than developing all the screens again we thought of calling the already developed website using the Iframe from the android app and then showing the website as per the screen size.
Android Frame work- Kotlin
My Application - Angular
But in this process when developers are calling iframe from their local they are not being able to load the website its throwing the below error
THE ERROR:**
''''Refused to frame "MY-URL-HERE" because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors ". Note that '' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches self's scheme. The scheme 'https:' must be added explicitly.''''
They said if the site loads when i open the below file then it works for them it seems (I don't have much exposure to android development)
<------------- index.html ----->
MY HTML page
<body>
 
 <iframe id="auto-examples" src="https://"MY-URL-HERE"/WarehouseTeam/Quality-Analytics" style="width: 100%; border: none;"></iframe>

<body>

`

I'm saving this file and then directly opening  on douple clicking it in window after which the page will be opened in google chrome right, On the page the site is not being rendered using the iframe.
When I run the same index.html in vs code them i'm able to fetch the page, but when I directly keep it in the html page and then open directly in chrome using
''''"C:\Users\rohith.kamasani\Downloads\text.html"'''' -- getting error
**error is **
THE ERROR:**
Refused to frame "MY-URL-HERE" because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors ". Note that '' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches self's scheme. The scheme 'https:' must be added explicitly.
BUt when in access the same page using the below link using vscode code preview extension i'm not getting error
**''''http://127.0.0.1:3000/c:/Users/rohith.kamasani/Downloads/text.html''''  -->not getting error
**
As per my research I found out**
While running directly from file:// and embedding an HTTPS iframe is difficult due to browser security, the best solution is either:
Temporarily disabling security in your browser for local development (not recommended for general use).
Setting up a local server, which solves the issue entirely without compromising security.
Can some one help me in this.
My Nginx configuration: Even after removing all the headers I'm getting the same error as mentioned above
ERROR:
Refused to frame "MY-URL-HERE" because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors ". Note that '' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches self's scheme. The scheme 'https:' must be added explicitly.
`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name uatoptimizer.seedworks.com "MY-URL-HERE";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors * MY-URL-HERE" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' MY-URL-HERE" always;

    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors *" always;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name "MY-URL-HERE";

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sdjv.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dchb.key; 


    # SSL settings
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Allow iframes from the same origin
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors * "MY-URL-HERE" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' "MY-URL-HERE" always;

    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors *" always;

    # Allow framing globally (if needed)
    # add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
    }
}'

I have tryed changing config of Nginx, But Nothing worked. Need some assistance on solving this.

I'd avoid the iframe altogether.  (browser's are locking those down pretty well these days and/or planning further restrictions) You usually don't want to allow other sites to frame your site, so using x-frame-options(deprecated) or frame-ancestors is a good idea.  Easiest would just be to create an app that simply launches the URL in the phone's browser.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When I render my url using IFrame in Android application, I should be able to see the page. As of now when Im testing in local host its showing permission problem
